# How to see what version of eclipse a program was running on

Tags: java

I was coding at school, but now that I'm out. I don't know what version of eclipse I was on. I get this error

"Cannot determine URI for '/HalliwillJ/src/halliwillJ/Gears.java'."

Comment: How do you see what kind of hammer was used to hang up a picture frame?

Comment: Where is your gears.java file?  You probably need to fix paths in your project.  That is from moving to a new file system, not a new code editor.

Comment: @DaveS That file is on a usb I moved from one computer to another. How do I fix paths

Comment: There's a File > Import option you should probably use instead. Some folders display and you can select "Existing Eclipse Project" as one of the options. It should be under General.

Answer (score 2):

An individual project will not store the Eclipse version number, but the entire workspace will. If you copied the workspace from school, look for this file in the root of your workspace directory:

```
workspace/.metadata/version.ini
```

In there you should find the version number under the platform key, for example:

```
org.eclipse.platform=4.6.1.v20160907-1200
```

You can find a general list of Eclipse version histories here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases

---

That said, it sounds like the Eclipse version is actually irrelevant and you really just need to be able to import old projects. Use the **File > Import** option:

[image]

And select **General > Existing Projects into Workspace**

[image]